How do I append Ben Ayers' Genshin Impact Shaders to my .pmx model? Not familiar with shaders - 3.6 LTS
How do I append the materials of these shaders to my .pmx models? I understand placing the node group but I don't understand how to connect the inputs and outputs.
Do I have to manually edit the node myself or is there any other way? The manual included in the file states that I have to append the materials and then add the node group to any material. However, I don't know how to do that. It instead appears as a separate material of my model's mesh.

If you are having problems, I suggest you contact the author directly. There's a reply from him to one of the comments on the page that you linked to saying "Please feel free to message me if you have any questions or need assistance. I'm always happy to help and resolve any issues."

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.
